# Best way to execute concurrent tasks with dependencies

Tags: scala, concurrency

I have several tasks I need to execute. Some have depedencies on other tasks. Is there anything in `scala.concurrent` (or other libraries) that would make this easier?

For example, there are four tasks, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. Task `A` depends on nothing, task `B` depends on tasks `A` and `D`, task `C` depends on `A` and `B`, and task `D` depends on nothing. Given a thread pool, do as much as possible as soon as possible.

This is similar to what Make or sbt can do with parallelizing tasks, using a dependency graph. (But neither of these are good fits, since I am not building; I am executing application logic which benefits from concurrent execution.)

Answer (score 2):

"A, B, C, and D. Task A depends on nothing, task B depends on tasks A and D, task C depends on A and B, and task D depends on nothing. "

```
val D = Future(…) //D depends on Nothing
val A = Future(…) //A depends on Nothing
val B = A zip D map (…) // B depends on A and D
val C = A zip B map (…) // C depends on A and B
```

Comment: Elegant, though `for` is more idiomatic than `zip`, avoids creating an extra intermediate future and works better when combining more than two futures.

Comment: Thanks for telling me how the API I was one of the core designers of is idiomatically used :-) Of course I focused on clarify in the example rather than performance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize :-) I meant the comment for others reading the answer and trying to derive working code from it. `zip` does make the dependencies very clear, and I actually wasn't unaware `Future` had a `zip` until reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you are looking for, but one the the main features of the Disruptor is to deal with task dependencies. It only works if you have fixed task dependencies, not dynamic tasks dependencies, because you need to set up this layout in the beginning.

https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor

As a nice bonus, it also is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about solutions for Scala, but some other alternatives for JVM are:

for Java8: [CompletableFuture](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Use `thenCombine` method to implement dependency on 2 tasks. Beware of a [bug for large dependence graphs](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jsr.166-concurrency/12547).

for Groovy: [GPARS dataflow](http://gpars.codehaus.org/Dataflow).

for Java7: [dataflow-for-java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/tree/master/df4j-core) - most compact and simple to use. I developed it specifically for tasks like yours. It has 2 base classes: for on-time tasks with dependencies on other tasks (org.df4j.core.func.Function), and for repeating tasks (org.df4j.core.actor.Actor - it is like Akka actor, but with several input ports). And it is an order of magnitude more performant (better say, order of magnitude less overhead) than GPARS.